# Setting classpath for a Java stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I've got an Oracle 10g database, and I have a third-party jar file.  I want to be able to run a SQL select query in my database that ultimately runs code in my third-party library to retrieve info for inclusion in a SQL result set.  I see lots of tutorials on "Java stored procedures" and these seem to be a promising way to do this, but none seem to use third-party libraries, and I can't seem to figure out how to specify a classpath for my jar file that will be recognized when I am running in Oracle.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can load the JAR file into the database using the loadjava tool.
This tool accepts also .class, .java, .properties, .sqlj, .ser, .jar, or .zip files.

See the manual ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/cheleven.htm#CACFHDJE ) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the jar to the Windows/Unix CLASSPATH system variable.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without altering the machine environment?