# setting third party jar in classpath while using oracle trigger

Tags: java, jar, oracle10g

I've got an Oracle 10g database, and I have a third-party jar file(MQ jars). I want to be able to run a trigger in my database that ultimately runs code in store procedure to operate MQ series and sending messages.
. I can't figure out how to specify a classpath for my jar file that will be recognized when I am executing trigger. How can I do this?

Comment: Your answer is [here in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529471/setting-classpath-for-a-java-stored-procedure-in-oracle) which discusses loading jars into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loadjava` (or `dbms_java.loadjava`) to load classes or JARs into the database; but for a third party JAR that seems unwieldy. If it's your database then you may be able to set the `CLASSPATH` to include the external files before starting the database. I don't think your user session `CLASSPATH` or any other environment variable (for whoever is taking the action that causes the trigger to fire) will ever have any effect, not least for security reasons - you don't want a user to be able to subvert the expected action by substituting their own Java code.