# How to include jar files to a Java Stored Procedure in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

I'm realizing a stored procedure and need now the ability to include jar files to my stored procedure, which do not belong to the standard deployment of the JRE. How can I do this? As I know wasn't it possible with Oracle 9 ...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the loadjava tool, it accepts jar files, too: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/cheleven.htm#CACFHDJE

See also this related question (copied the above link from there):
[Setting classpath for a Java stored procedure in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529471/setting-classpath-for-a-java-stored-procedure-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

I normally use this console command to add new jars to oracle:

```
exec dbms_java.loadjava('D:\temp\jcifs-1.3.19.jar');
```

In my case I added this library to connecto to windows shared folders from a oracle linux installation (smb). After the installation you may need to grant your user with permissions.