# PL/SQL Count pages from pdf blob

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a situation in which I have a blob file whose type is .PDF and I need to count the pages in the PDF. Is there a way to do it without any external (3rd party) libraries? I know that there is PL/PDF tool but I need to do it only in PL/SQL. I am using Oracle 11g version, and the files is sitting in the table.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this thread on [the OTN PL/SQL forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/973784). Bear in mind is that different PDF producers may have different structures. So, depending on where your PDFs come from, you may need a flexible (i.e. complex) search pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go with Java in the Oracle database.
Check how to do it with Java only [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134949/determine-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026971/page-count-of-pdf-with-java/6037465).

Next steps would be to :

- [load the required JAR libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173304/how-to-include-jar-files-to-a-java-stored-procedure-in-oracle) in the Oracle database
- [create a Java Source in the database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chfive.htm#BABBCFHE) with the java code in it
- create a PL/SQL function that will wrap the Java class (once the source is compiled).
- Use this PL/SQL function to get the number of pages in your PDF through Java.

Those are the main lines but I think it's the best way if you want to stay with open source and free software.

Comment: You have an interesting definition of *"without any external (3rd party) libraries"*.

Comment: ok, my bad. then the post mentioned before might be better suited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I searched all over the internet, there is no option to count the numbers of PDF just with PL/SQL, so I will go with this answer, I will create a java class and I will count the numbers with java.

Comment: Ok, just take care that "Java in the DB" is enabled in your Oracle production database.
It's enabled by default but sometimes DBAs remove it when creating the databases.